# How to manage dynamic time based task in wso2?

Tags: wso2, activemq-classic, alert, wso2-esb

I wish to raise an alert to the user who can set his ETA when he registered. So if he is unable to reach in time then I wish to raise an alert to the user.How can i achieve this? Ii refereed TASK SCHEDULING in wso2esb but it has static request and static time defined and my time is different for every user. How would i do it dynamically?
Even I tried ACTIVE MQ scheduling but of no use. Any help for this?

```
PROPERTY NAME   TYPE    DESCRIPTION
AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY long    The time in milliseconds that a message will wait before being scheduled to be delivered by the broker
AMQ_SCHEDULED_PERIOD    long    The time in milliseconds to wait after the start time to wait before scheduling the message again
AMQ_SCHEDULED_REPEAT    int The number of times to repeat scheduling a message for delivery
AMQ_SCHEDULED_CRON  String  Use a Cron entry to set the schedule.
```

i added proxy like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="JMSSCHEDULE11"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
         <log level="full"/>
         <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
         <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED"
                   value="true"
                   scope="axis2"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property name="AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY"
                   value="3000000000000000"
                   scope="transport"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="jms:/JMSSCHEDULE?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&java.naming.provider.url=tcp://127.0.0.1:61616&transport.jms.DestinationType=queue"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
   </target>
   <parameter name="delay">300000000000</parameter>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

>

Even though its not working

Comment: can we able to use this property in wso2esb  ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY

Comment: i am following this link http://www.devteam.gr/blog/?p=265&lang=en

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the scheduler support in activemq which is disabled by default.

You need to edit the file in the location : D:\Installed\apache-activemq-5.9-SNAPSHOT\conf\activemq.xml

```
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" advisorySupport="false" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}" schedulerSupport="true">
```

Once you enable the scheduler you can see a new tab "**Scheduled**" on admin web console of ActiveMQ

```
 http://localhost:8161/admin/scheduled.jsp
```

Answer (score 0):

you need add this prperty and need to modify activemq.xml file as schedulerSupport="true

```
<property name="AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY"
                   value="3000000000000000"
                   scope="transport"
                   type="STRING"/>
```